# How to measure current in a DC series parallel circuit using a DMM?

Tags: current, dc

Today in class I was given the task of building a circuit in a simulator, then building it on a breadboard to measure the current/voltage/resistance etc. This was my first time working with a series-parallel circuit, and I just couldn't get the right measurements for current.

I understand that the ammeter must be in series with the circuit, but it seemed as though no way of breaking the circuits would give me the expected current.

Ex:

[image: example circuit]

How could I break the circuit to measure the resistance through R4 in this diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using an ammeter to measure current through the resistor, you disconnect one of the nodes of the branch you're measuring through (so top or bottom of R4)

Then you hook up one probe to each part you broke, so you re-complete the circuit

Warning: If you connect the ammeter in parallel instead of series you'll blow the fuse

[image]

Comment: How will the fuse blow if its not connected????

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: I think echad is warning against connecting the DMM in parallel with the resistor, while the resistor is still in circuit. Under that condition the DMM will short out the resistor.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky I meant if it's connected in parallel with the resistor instead of series

Comment: Parallel connection is unlikely to blow the fuse unless you also short out R1 and R6. But it'll give very misleading results, which is probably worse. But if R4's value is known, why not simply measure the voltage across it?

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the end of R4 that connects to R6. Connect the positive lead of the DMM to the dangling end of R4. Connect the negative lead of the DMM to the point where R6 and R5 join.

Make sure the DMM test leads are plugged in to the correct jacks for measuring current, rather than voltage or resistance. If you still have trouble, there should be a fuse in the DMM to protect it when measuring current. Find the fuse and make sure it's not blown.